Ubuntu 22.04.4 live server uses the autoinstall function to deploy, prompt: 'version' is a required property
ERROR root:30 finish: subiquity/core_validation: FAIL: 'version' is a required property
To facilitate troubleshooting, I directly quoted the simplest configuration of the official document and found the same error.How to solve this problem?

https://canonical-subiquity.readthedocs-hosted.com/en/latest/tutorial/creating-autoinstall-configuration.html

#cloud-config
autoinstall:
    version: 1
    identity:
        hostname: hostname
        username: username
        password: $crypted_pass

I installed the system through the USB boot drive. By reading the official documentation, I found that in this scenario I can directly rename the "user-data" file to "autoinstall.yaml" and put the file in the root directory of the boot disk to achieve automatic installation.


@DavidDE The question seems clear to me as currently written.

So I am stupid removed my comment.
